# Utilitarian introduction to commutative algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation, complex-geometry

My goal is to have some good handling over the jujutsu of basic commutative algebra (eg: the depth and difficulty of Atiyah-Mcdonald) so that I can properly read books on complex curves/complex geometry/algebraic geometry.

Atiyah-Mcdonald is usually referred to as the canonical choice in this case, but my main problem (difficulty/densenss are secondary problems) with Atiyah-Mcdonald is that it's too much dry, and most (if not all) topics seem to be rather unmotivated

Is there any good complex geometry/complex curves/algebraic geometry books out there which develops commutative algebra on an "utilitarian" or need based basis ? I'm told that Fulton/Vakil doese that but I'm not sure how good are those books.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Commutative algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry by Eisenbud is the best 
for motivation but it’s also enormous, although you don’t have to read the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following [lecture notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013.pdf). As you can already see on the first pages, the author really wants to convey geometric intuition and in my opinion he succeeds to do so throughout the entire set of notes. Afterwards you can even continue with his [notes on algebraic geometry](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf) which are equally great.